# passProps not setting props for ListItem for react-native

Tags: react-native

I am using a ListItem onPress to navigate to a different route using the code below.

```
onPress(item) {
 this.props.navigator.push({
  component: Areas,
  passProps: {
    new_id: item.new_id,
  }
});
}
_renderItem(item) {
  return (
    <ListItem item={item} onPress={ () => this.onPress(item) }/>
  );
 }
```

However, the this.props.new_id is undefined in the next component.

```
export default class areas extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  console.log(" UUUU ");
  console.log(this.props.new_id);
}
render(){
  return (
    <Text style={styles.liText}>AAA {this.props.new_id} BBB</Text>
  );
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('areas', () => areas);
```

Is there anything I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: What does your Navigator's `renderScene` function look like? That is where you would make sure to push everything in route.passProps down to the component you render in that function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found the answer. I looked in renderScene which was not passing the props properly.

I fixed it in the following way:
Initial:

```
return React.createElement(route.component, { navigator });
```

To:

```
return React.createElement(route.component, { ...this.props, ...route.passProps, route, navigator } )
```

This seems the pass the props.